# Visual Studio won't let me add a COM control to a form in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, com, activex

I'm trying to add an **ActiveX** control to my form in **Visual Studio's** designer mode and it prompts

`Failed to import the ActiveX control. Please ensure it is properly registered.`.

It's in the case that I have registered it properly. To prove my word, I can add the same control in the same machine to some other project's form! I just can't do it to the project I want.

These two projects are almost the same and I can not find the difference that might have caused this. Can anyone suggest what might have gone wrong?

**[UPDATE]**

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.30319.1 and both projects are C# WinForms.

Comment: What is your Visual Studio version and what kind of project is that (WPF or WinForms, C#, C++ or VB)?

Comment: In cases like this, you'll want to run Aximp.exe from the Visual Studio Command Prompt.  You'll get better diagnostics.  And the interop libraries you need.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks Hans. Aximp.exe can generate the Ax???.dll file without any errors. But I still have difficulties adding the control to a form. I tried manually adding the two generated .dll files (Ax???.dll and ???.dll) to my project but yet I face the same error message as before when I try to add a control of this `ActiveX` to my form. Was I supposed to use the two generated .dll files? Or I was just supposed to see if the Aximp.exe manages to generate them?